# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el intérvalo de los valores del eje "y" en un gráfico de barras hecho en matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

supongamos que tengo el siguiente código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[2,3,4]
y=[1,2,3]
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Mi problema con este código es que a pesar de que sí imprime el gráfico correctamente, en el eje "y" muestra valores como 0.5,1,1.5 etc...(en intérvalos de 0.5) hasta llegar a 3 y quisiera que el eje "y" solo mostrara los valores que tiene cada una de las "x", es decir 1,2 y 3. Cómo logro hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante [`plt.yticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html) puedes especificar no sólo los puntos del eje Y que deben ser etiquetados, sino también, si quieres, qué deben mostar esas etiquetas (por defecto mostrarán el número correspondiente).

Por ejemplo, se le puede pasar una lista con los puntos en que debe haber ticks. En este caso le paso la misma lista `y`:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[2,3,4]
y=[1,2,3]
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.yticks(y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Resultado]

También se le puede pasar, además de las "coordenadas" de los tikcs, las etiquetas a mostrar, por ejemplo:

```
plt.yticks(y, ["Bajo", "Medio", "Alto"])
```

[image: Resultado 2]

Comment: Muy bien, ya ahora me quedó todo claro.